# Best way to Parse json files from post request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

**Scenario:** I have a Nodejs rest server which accepts some json file,parse it and then add it to some DB. I expect hundreds of hits per second.

**Requirement**:Only insertions are to be done parsing the json from request.Since nodejs is single-threaded and JSON.parse is also synchronised, How can i increase the performace? Or which must be the correct design pattern for maximum performance in nodejs?

Comment: You may use [worker threads](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads) in node.

Comment: Do you have a sample of your json data ?

Answer (score 1):

Before designing a more complex server (maybe with worker threads), you need to profile the actual performances. The bottleneck might not be the json parsing.